# Time stamp to show when file was last updated by pressing F9 (just editing not sufficient)

Tags: vba, excel, timestamp, refresh

I want to add a time stamp to my Excel sheets which shows me when the file was last updated. I used this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False

    Range("D13") = Now()

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The problem with this code is that it shows the last time when a value was **added**, but this value might be not the real one, because the **formulas were not calculated** (not pressed F9, disabled automatic calculation). Instead of showing the last time when a value was added, I would like to show the last time the formulas were updated.

Is it possible to add a time stamp which shows when the last time the Excel sheet was **re-calculated**?

Comment: look into worksheets_calculate event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **create a public Boolean** that you set to *True when there is modification* and use `Worksheet_Calculate` *event to update the time stamp if* that Boolean is True :

```
Public HasChanged As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Application.EnableEvents = False

    If HasChanged Then Range("D13") = Now()
    HasChanged = False

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    HasChanged = True
End Sub
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you very much!! Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: @Jekapeka : Glad I could help! ;) As you are new to SO, just a few pointers : When your problem is solved, you can validate the answer by clicking in the tick right under the up/down vote arrows. Use up/down votes on each posts(Q or A) that you find useful/useless(or bad quality). And take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (even if this question was fine, it is always useful to know about those)